# jQuery don't load for a child theme in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I would like to add an HTML code in my child theme to add an icon in my child theme in Wordpress. Currently, that's like that :

[image: First]

And I would like to add a Youtube icon like that (that's not in the theme, that's why I want to add it with HTML) :

[image: Second]

So I set up the function.php code with :

```
    <?php

function mytheme_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('mytheme_functions', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/myScript.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
wp_enqueue_script('jq_ui', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js', array('jquery')); //Not sure if we can use the CDN here instead of a local version.
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts' );

?>
```

Here is my jQuery code :

```
 $(document).ready(function($) { 

$(".social-google-plus").append('<li class="social-youtube"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/TWorldAngels" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>');


});
```

My jQuery code is in a /js folder which is in my child theme. But it doesn't work. What is wrong ? Thanks guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sure that mine loads right.

Perhaps the $ is generating the issue (is how WordPress prevents conflicts between js libraries).

Try the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $(".social-google-plus").append('<li class="social-youtube"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/TWorldAngels" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>');
});
```

(I haven't tested your code)

if this does not resolve it, can you provide further details? Console errors?

Comment: -1- Check 'Scripts' tab in Chrome Developer Tools: jQuery should load from 'wp-includes'.
-2- If you have a 'js/functions.js' in your child theme template, it doesn't load by default. Add the next script tag to your child's header.php:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/functions.js"></script>`